# Maintain equation to a cell which might be moved

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

On one sheet of a spreadsheet I have a list of student name, sorted alphabetically, followed by their scores on various assignments and tests.

On another sheet, I calculate the scores based on the individual questions of the test. I have the same list of students so on the second sheet I enter the equation `=Sheet1!A4`, which I then drag down. This works great, until I decide to resort either page.

Suppose I sort sheet 1 based on the students' current overall grade. This throws off the labels on sheet 2 (and the rest of them).

*How do I set the equations to link to the same cell, even if it's resorted?*

**Edit** A sample has been requested. I do not know how to upload a file here or type in a sample spreadsheet. Here is a link to a  [sample file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=37689354588156197600)

Notice the first page lists the "students" (names and grades changed) sorted by section. Each section is listed on its own tab.

The 2nd, 3rd, and 4th tabs reference the students names. The first cells grades reference to the other tabs.

Notice the third tab (section 2), the first name is Wong Wei and the second is Anders Andersen. *On the first tab, sort by student, then return to the second tab and the names have changed. If I sort within any of the tabs, then their overall grades change*. That is what I'm trying to program around.

I do not have enough experience to try VLOOKUP on my own or try to create a relationship between the tables (although now I notice that comment includes a link to instructions).

Comment: There is no easy solution for that.  You can use e.g. VLOOKUP to link to the student name instead of just referring to a cell.

Comment: You can try to [create a relationship](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-relationship-between-tables-in-Excel-fe1b6be7-1d85-4add-a629-8a3848820be3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) between tables

Comment: @MátéJuhász Can you guys elaborate? Maybe with a full answer.

Comment: @Raystafarian Can you guys elaborate? Maybe with a full answer.

Comment: Please post sample data (with desired output), currently your question is too broad for further evaluation.

Comment: We both told you something to try - go give it a try and then let us know if you run into trouble

Comment: In my opinion it isn't feasible to store data in this way. You can enter a formula on your Overall sheet to link the Quiz/E1/E2 data [cell D2 formula would be =VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'Section "&C2&"'!"&"A2:D5"),2,0)   which can be dragged down to the end] but this won't overcome the sorting problem as you explain, because your primary key moves and your section sheets will reference something else. May be able to use an array formula to build your Section sheets to solve this, but it doesn't help the fact the data isn't stored in the right way, and when you add more names it will go wrong again.

Comment: @David (or at anyone) How would you store the data to solve this? It's a fairly important issue for me.

Comment: Every field (per record) in only one place. For example, your Overall sheet could contain all records with all fields; or your other sheets could each contain a selection of records, but each record would have all fields stored there. This is *if* you need to do the sorting on the Overall sheet.